# Process last n records in pyspark kafka streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I need to do some operations on last 100 000 records (customer bills) of different stores each for every five minutes. What is the best approach or steps I need to follow in **pyspark structured streaming**? **Input source is Kafka**.
And also I have to gradually delete the old records beyond 100k records of each store, because I need only recent 100k records per every store at any time.

For example, I need to find out the details of the product 'p1' from last 100k records of store 'S1', and last 100k records from store 'S2' and so on.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. People living elsewhere aren't going to understand what are "lakh" records.

Comment: sure @JamesZ, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Structured streaming don't have such option. One workaround is estimate messages per second, then calulate how long needed for 100K records. Finally, you can use `startingTimestamp`. Please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries